# Vue Components not showing up using passport in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

As you can see from the title I am trying out Laravel 5.3 and passport.

So I have gone through the  steps to install Laravel passport and as far as I can see everything is in place.

I have put the corresponding Vue components into the markup of my home.blade.php as follows to test as per the docs which I have done like so

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<passport-clients></passport-clients>
<passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
<passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
@endsection
```

Vue is detected as running in my dev tools however no Vue components are showing up.

Here is my app.js

```
 Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});


Vue.component(
'passport-clients',
require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);
```

I am getting the error

```
 vue.common.js?4a36:1019 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <passport-clients> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Any idea how I can fix this?I am fairly new to Vue

Comment: Have you imported the components in your app.js file?

Comment: Yes, i have  imported it indeed

Comment: Yeah exactly that

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/W93QLHaj) is the code for importing. 
I had actually forgotten to run gulp (sorry its late). However now i have it is coming up with some errors in console atleast. 

    vue.common.js?4a36:1019 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <passport-clients> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Then the same for both other components.

Comment: Yeah i have published the components and [here](http://pastebin.com/mNMUjkc6) is the entire file to show you how i imported the components. I tried taking out the example component however then the errors didn't come up in console for the other tags however they still didn't load.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thanks allot. Could you put it as an answer so i can mark it as correct please?

Comment: Thanks all done and i marked as correct! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `app.js` file, import the components immediately below or in place of the `example` component, but before creating the new `Vue` object where it gets bound to the DOM.

Don't forget to run `gulp` as well. :)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with the following resolution with Laravel 5.4:

Find `resources/assets/app.js`.

1. put all `Vue.component...` before `new Vue` (not after)
2. in each `Vue.component`'s `import`, append `.default`

```
Vue.component(
    'passportclients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue').default
);

Vue.component(
    'passportauthorizedclients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue').default
);

Vue.component(
    'passportpersonalaccesstokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue').default
);
```

And then run `npm run dev` again.

Comment: With laravel 5.6 the first solution worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out that this matters:
put the code

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

at the END of the app.js file.

That started showing the components on the webpage.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of the above answer

Answer (score 0):

Tarun is correct:

Make sure you include your **vue** references in `app.js` before:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Also try Ctrl / Cmd + F5 to clear browser cache while you refresh.

Answer (score -2):

I have fixed that issue, we do not need to include any Vue libraries, laravel by default provides this (this is  for laravel 5.4 and > ) :

**Go to your project-folder/public/js/app.js**

Find the code where your passport clients, passport authorized clients and passport-personal-access-tokens are registered.

Replace the **code** with :

```
Vue.component('example-component', webpack_require(41));

Vue.component('passport-clients', webpack_require(44));

Vue.component('passport-authorized-clients', webpack_require(50));

Vue.component('passport-personal-access-tokens', webpack_require(55));

var app = new Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

**Note : Register the Vue.component before "Var app = new Vue"**